# pulling the following information with a single select

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following information in my mysql table
[image]

Eventually I would like to make a select that would count the entries for a page_id but just for the specific date , meaning I would like to have the following output:

```
84 - 7 - 09/23/2013
85 - 4 - 09/23/2013
84 - 1 - 09/24/2013
```

Can it be done in a single select ?

Comment: `GROUP BY`, `COUNT`....

Comment: Not really , I would like to count the rows and not summing up a column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select page_id, count(*), date 
from table_name 
group by page_id, date
```

Comment: Thanks , was missing the second group by

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT page_id, count(page_id), date
FROM table
GROUP BY page_id, date
```

You need to `SELECT` the 3 fields. Then you need to `COUNT` one of those (page_id) since you need to count how many repetitions you got. And the last step, for the query to run (and also to make sense) is to `GROUP BY` the other 2 fields.

Hope you get a clearer idea on how to query the table.